# Parse Youtube api in Swift 4 using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, alamofire

I'm trying to parse Youtube api in using Alamofire in Swift 4 
so far i did get the results and all fine but i'm having trouble accessing the "items"

so basically i want to access title, description, medium thumbnails url and resultsPerPage.

i tried a lot of solutions but non if them worked for me specially i'm using Swift4 and Alamofire

JSON:

```
{  
   "kind":"youtube#searchListResponse",
   "etag":"\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/N6oV8CScLhAtqc_fDnA3Nw4U3RA\"",
   "nextPageToken":"CBkQAA",
   "regionCode":"US",
   "pageInfo":{  
      "totalResults":922098,
      "resultsPerPage":25
   },
   "items":[  
      {  
         "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
         "etag":"\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Oxu5v7t2PHcDK4wvSo-xsIp3Raw\"",
         "id":{  },
         "snippet":{  
            "publishedAt":"2011-03-21T08:32:25.000Z",
            "channelId":"UC1r4VtVE__5K6c_L_3Vlxxg",
            "title":"fouseyTUBE",
            "description":"",
            "thumbnails":{  
               "default":{  
                  "url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oBs78-0JLws/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/zKWHSghRD3U/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
               },
               "medium":{  
                  "url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oBs78-0JLws/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/zKWHSghRD3U/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
               },
               "high":{  
                  "url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oBs78-0JLws/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/zKWHSghRD3U/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
               }
            },
            "channelTitle":"fouseyTUBE",
            "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
         }
      }
]
}
```

My Code :

```
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
        let parameters = ["q": searchText, "maxResults": 25, "part": "snippet", "type":"video", "key": "MY_YOUTUBE_API_KEY"] as [String : Any]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData { (dataResponse) in
            if let err = dataResponse.error {
                print("Failed to contact server", err)
                return
            }

            guard let data = dataResponse.data else {return}
            do{
                let searchResult = try
                    JSONDecoder().decode(SearchResults.self, from: data)
                print("Results Count:", searchResult.kind)
                searchResult.items.forEach({ (data) in

                    print(searchResult.items["data"]["items"])
                })
                self.musics = searchResult.items
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }catch let decodeErr {
                print("Failed to Descode: ", decodeErr)
            }


        }
    }

    struct SearchResults: Decodable{
        let kind: String
        let items: [Music]
    }
```

Music.Swift file

```
struct Music: Decodable {
    var etag: String?
    var kind: String?
    //let time: String
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating decodable struct for each nested elements like so,

```
struct PageInfo: Decodable {
    var totalResults = 0
    var resultsPerPage = 0
}


struct Snippet: Decodable {
    var channelId = ""
    var title = ""
    var description = ""
    var channelTitle = ""
    var thumbnails: Thumbnail
}


struct ChannelURL: Decodable {
    var url = ""
}

struct Thumbnail: Decodable {
    var medium: ChannelURL
    var high: ChannelURL
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    var kind = ""
    var etag = ""
    var snippet: Snippet

}


struct Result: Decodable {
    var kind = ""
    var etag = ""
    var pageInfo: PageInfo
    var items: [Item]
}
```

And then proceed with the decoding. The following decoding works with your response above.

```
    do {


        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
        debugPrint(decoded)


        //Now access the data
        print(decoded.pageInfo.resultsPerPage) // 25

        //since the items is array we take first for now
        if  let firstItem = decoded.items.first {
            //to print the first one
            print(firstItem.snippet.channelTitle) // "fouseyTUBE"

            //same for URL
            print(firstItem.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url) // https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oBs78-0JLws/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/zKWHSghRD3U/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
        }


    } catch {
        debugPrint("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

This is the best case scenario were all data is present. So you will have to modify your structure accordingly making some values ``

Comment: Worked Perfectly.

Comment: what if i don't wanna get first and i wanna get all results ? which are for example 25

Comment: That is easily accomplished using loop. right?   `e.g : decoded.items.forEach { print ($0.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url)} `

Comment: it's great but after getting the data it only display 1 item in the table view, but in the console it displays the 25 one, here is what it looks like on this [Image](https://preview.ibb.co/gnttep/Untitled.png) and i want to use the image and the snippets data at the same time like how i can use this image and this data together i'm sorry im a bit beginner in IOS and swift. thank you.

Comment: I believe you are only using one snippet in table view. You should modify this line ‘self.snippets = [items.snippet]’ to ‘self.snippets.append(items.snippet)’. This will add all the snippet to array and then you should be able display all results

Comment: terrific, worked perfect, thank you for helping me i'm just starting with swift just had to add `self.snippets.removeAll()` to clear results when search and append the new one.

Comment: You didn't add videoID here. How to add it & where?